# How can I make the action loop when it get one data and change action immediately when it get other data？

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

This is a webrobot design by rpi, how can I make the action loop when it gets one data from webpage and change actions immediately when it gets other data?
For example, if you get data 1, then loop action 1. If you get data 5 when loop action 1, then the action is changed to action 5.

```
@app.route('/<data>')
def reroute(data):
    Data = int(data)

    if Data == 1:
        driver.turn_left()
    elif Data == 2:
        driver.forward()
    elif Data == 3:
        driver.turn_right()
    elif Data == 4:
        driver.backward()
    elif Data == 5:
        driver.rob_back()
    elif Data == 6:
        driver.rob_power_off()
    elif Data == 7:
        driver.camera_up()
    elif Data == 8:
        driver.camera_down()
    elif Data == 9:
        driver.camera_left()
    elif Data == 10:
        driver.camera_right()
    elif Data == 11:
        driver.camera_pwr_on()
    elif Data == 12:
        driver.rob_pwr_on()

    response = make_response(redirect(url_for('index')))
    return(response)
```

Comment: Better you paste the code as text.

Comment: You should look into the `break` statement:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_break_statement.htm

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `how can I make it loop when it gets one data from webpage`. You have it set up so that one command is issued per request. So if you want multiple commands, make multiple requests.